# Not able to send Image in chat Application

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I tried to share the image in the chat app.But was not able to successfully share it.
It's selecting the image from the gallery but not appearing in the chat and not getting saved in the firebase also. Below is my Chat.xml file and UserChat.java file.

I am not able to find the solution for it.

**//XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity.UserChatActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:civ_border_color="#D21CB4F5"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receivername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messageAdapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mesbox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mesbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/attachment"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="540dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#0381C5">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/clip"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="540dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#431CB4F5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editmessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="540dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#0381C5">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/send"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**// JAVA code**

```
package com.example.chatapp.Activity;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String ReceiverImage;
String ReceiverUID;
String ReceiverName;
String SenderUID;
String senderRoom;
String receiverRoom;

public static String sImage;
public static String rImage;

CircleImageView profile_image;
TextView receivername;

CardView attachment;
EditText editmessage;
CardView sendbutton;

FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseDatabase database;

RecyclerView messageAdapter;
ArrayList<Messages> messagesArrayList;

MessagesAdapter adapter;

private String checker = "", myURL = "";
private StorageTask uploadTask;
private Uri fileUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_chat);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    ReceiverImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiverImage");
    ReceiverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    ReceiverUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

    messagesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    receivername = findViewById(R.id.receivername);

    messageAdapter = findViewById(R.id.messageAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    messageAdapter.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(UserChatActivity.this, messagesArrayList);
    messageAdapter.setAdapter(adapter);

    attachment = findViewById(R.id.attachment);
    editmessage = findViewById(R.id.editmessage);
    sendbutton = findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);

    Picasso.get().load(ReceiverImage).into(profile_image);
    receivername.setText("" + ReceiverName);

    SenderUID = fAuth.getUid();

    senderRoom = SenderUID + ReceiverUID;
    receiverRoom = ReceiverUID + SenderUID;

    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user").child(fAuth.getUid());
    DatabaseReference chatReference = database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).child("messages");


    chatReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            messagesArrayList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                messagesArrayList.add(messages);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            sImage = snapshot.child("imageUri").getValue().toString();
            rImage = ReceiverImage;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                    {
                      "Image", "Documents"
                    };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserChatActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select File");

            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        checker = "image";

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 438);
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        checker = "pdf";
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });

    sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editmessage.getText().toString();

            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(UserChatActivity.this, "Insert Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            editmessage.setText("");
            Date date = new Date();

            Messages messages = new Messages(message, SenderUID, date.getTime());

            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .push()
                    .setValue(messages).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            database.getReference().child("chats")
                                    .child(receiverRoom)
                                    .child("messages")
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(messages).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 438 && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        fileUri = data.getData();

        if (!checker.equals("image"))
        {

        }
        else if (checker.equals("image"))
        {
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Image Files").child(fAuth.getUid());;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Please someone help me to solve it.**

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());` in the second callback. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo where I have add this line?

Comment: You don't. You should add it and check if something gets printed out in the logcat.

Comment: 2022-07-22 13:38:00.225 1795-2495/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-07-22 13:38:00.225 1795-2495/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't provide information so we can help.

Comment: @AlexMamo can I share you the project file. That you can check what's the error.

Comment: I can see only one usage of storageReference. Where is the rest of your code which is saving your image? You need to pass an array of bytes/file/inputstream and save your image to storage. 

It should be like that (simplified)
Getting URI in onActivityResult -> opening a stream with this URI -> passing this stream to Firebase -> then you'll have an UploadTask.

Please, read this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory. You should always start from reading documentation.

Comment: @PineapplePie storangeReference is their in last.